# Disable color change of anchor tag when visited

Tags: html, css, anchor

I have to disable the color change of an anchor tag when visited. I did this:

```
a:visited{ color: gray }
```

(The link is gray in color before visited.) But this is a way where I explicitly state the color after the link is visited, which is again a color change.

How can I disable the color change of an anchor tag when visited without doing any explicit color changes?

Answer (score 127, accepted):

You can't. You can only style the visited state.

For other people who find this, make sure that you have them in the right order:

```css
a {color:#FF0000;}         /* Unvisited link  */
a:visited {color:#00FF00;} /* Visited link    */
a:hover {color:#FF00FF;}   /* Mouse over link */
a:active {color:#0000FF;}  /* Selected link   */
```

Comment: To be really anal about it, shouldn't the `a` be `a:link`?

Comment: I guess so, though I rarely do that.

Comment: @nikc.org not anal at all, `a:link` and `a` are **not** the same. An anchor does not necessarily have to be a link. It normally changes color only when it contains a link.

Comment: or better yet
```css
a, a:visited, a:hover, a:active { color:#00FF00; }
```

Comment: You only care about `a:link` if you have anchors that do not have `href`, which can happen if a lot of content are auto-generated. If you care about styling a link vs a non-link, then you use `a:link`, otherwise it doesn't matter.

Comment: In my case, it was needed to add this too: `a:focus{color: #your_desired_color}`

Answer (score 279):

If you just want the anchor color to stay the same as the anchor's parent element you can leverage inherit:

```
a, a:visited, a:hover, a:active {
  color: inherit;
}
```

Notice there is no need to repeat the rule for each selector; just use a comma separated list of selectors (order matters for anchor pseudo elements).  Also, you can apply the pseudo selectors to a class if you want to selectively disable the special anchor colors:

```
.special-link, .special-link:visited, .special-link:hover, .special-link:active {
  color: inherit;
}
```

Your question only asks about the visited state, but I assumed you meant all of the states.  You can remove the other selectors if you want to allow color changes on all but visited.

Comment: This worked great, thanks!  As a note to others, you may have to add !important to the color tag for it to properly take depending on what else is in your website: color: inherit !important;

Comment: In Chrome this simply renders the link text in black.

Comment: Is there any way to have `a:link` be the default link color (usually blue) *and* have `a:visited` inherit from that, without hard-coding "blue" anywhere?

Answer (score 15):

For `:hover` to override `:visited`, and to make sure `:visited` is the same as the initial color, `:hover` must come after `:visited`.

So if you want to disable the color change, `a:visited` must come before `a:hover`. Like this:

```
a { color: gray; }
a:visited { color: orange; }
a:hover { color: red; }
```

To disable `:visited` change you would style it with non-pseudo class:

```
a, a:visited { color: gray; }
a:hover { color: red; }
```

Comment: Am I looking at this wrong or are you doing the exact opposite of what's said in the quote? According to W3Schools it's 1) `a:link`, `a:visited` 2) `a:hover` 3) `a:active`

Answer (score 11):

It’s possible to use the `LinkText` [system color value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value#system_colors) from the CSS 4 Color Module to obtain the browser default value if one wishes to defer to that.

```css
a:visited { color: LinkText; }
```

```html
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com">link</a>
```

However note:

> These values may also be used in other contexts, but are not widely supported by browsers.

It at least appears to work in Firefox 98 and Chromium 99.

Answer (score 1):

If you use some pre-processor like SASS, you can use `@extend` feature:

```
a:visited {
  @extend a;
}
```

As a result you will see automatically-added `a:visited` selector for every style with `a` selector, so be carefully with it, because your style-table may be increase in size very much.

As a compromise you can add @extend only in those block wich you really need.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this issue by calling `a:link` and `a:visited` selectors together. And follow it with `a:hover` selector.

```
a:link, a:visited
{color: gray;}
a:hover
{color: skyblue;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if I set a color for `a:visited` it is not good: you must know the default color of tag `a` and every time synchronize it with `a:visited`.

I don't want know about the default color (it can be set in `common.css` of your application, or you can using outside styles).

I think it's nice solution:

`HTML`:

```
<body>
    <a class="absolute">Test of URL</a>
    <a class="unvisited absolute" target="_blank" href="google.ru">Test of URL</a>
</body>
```

`CSS`:

```
.absolute{
    position: absolute;
}
a.unvisited, a.unvisited:visited, a.unvisited:active{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: Who set me minus, can you write why you did it? Of course you can use your colors of A tag. But i written if you are using default brower's colors

Answer (score 0):

For those who are dynamically applying classes (i.e. active):
Simply add a "div" tag inside the "a" tag with an href attribute:

```
<a href='your-link'>
  <div>
    <span>your link name</span>
  </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

Either delete the selector or set it to the same color as your text appears normally.

Comment: OP says without doing any explicit color changes

Answer (score -1):

```
a {
    color: orange !important;
}
```

`!important` has the effect that the property in question cannot be overridden unless another `!important` is used. It is generally considered bad practice to use `!important` unless absolutely necessary; however, I can't think of any other way of ‘disabling’ `:visited` using CSS only.

Answer (score -10):

Use:

```
a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

But it will only affect links that haven't been clicked on yet.

Comment: The question asked about color, not text-decoration.