# Blue when I click on links

Tags: css, hyperlink, onclick

On my website, when I click on a link that has a href or onclick reference, it gets a blue highlight that ends my design. How to remove? See an example in the menu icon that has an 'onclick' reference, I managed to take a print right from the time I click on it on my phone.
How can I remove this?

[The icon is blue that I did not program, all links on the site look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhyhB.jpg)

Comment: check similar request which is answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7291873/disable-color-change-of-anchor-tag-when-visited

Answer (score 0):

If a `media screen` solution suit you. That can work:

```
@media screen and (max-width:500px) {
  .selector:active, .selector:hover {
    background-color: unset;
    color: #999;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that we're working with an "a" element you can easily get rid of the blue highlighting with basic css:

```
a:hover, a:focus, a:active {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #3c4146  /* Just a mild gray, you can change this to whatever you want */
}
```

In the case of a different element, which in your case looks like a btn/div with a set background, you can adapt the css to it.
You can set the bg back to its original color when you either hover, focus or set the element to active.

```
.element:focus, .element:active, .element:hover {
  background-color: #000000;  /* Use the original element background-color here */
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me! Hope u fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
a {
```

-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent !important;

outline: none !important;
}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I was testing my new pet project on my phone and I also had an issue with BLUE outline/highlight flashing effect upon TAP.

For me @RedhaBenKortbi answer worked.

After applying this CSS to  tags, the links were no longer flashing with the blue-ish outline/highlight when you click.

```
.scaledImage a {
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent !important;
}
```

Doc says:

> -webkit-tap-highlight-color is a non-standard CSS property that sets the color of the highlight that appears over a link while it's being
> tapped. The highlighting indicates to the user that their tap is being
> successfully recognized, and indicates which element they're tapping
> on.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-tap-highlight-color

Comment: The `text-decoration: none;` answers don't work for mobile devices if you are tapping on a div/img . That's when the annoying flashing shows up and you do not want that on mobile if you have your own custom background-color transitions etc. you want to turn that off with that "webkit" property above 100%